# How to Automatically add members to Google Groups from trigger of new PayPal Subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, google-groups

It is about Automatically Subscription Payment - Site Members Access.

I have google site with Training contact for subscription members only.

They pay with Paypal Subscription
and i manage the list of members with Google groups that access the site.

I want to know:
How to Automatically add members to Google Groups from trigger of new PayPal Subscription?

Right now i am adding new members manually to the google groups
after i receive Paypal subscription message in my Gmail,
but i want to make that process automatically.
When new customer pay and become Paypal subscription - they will have instant access to the site.

How to do it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's [IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) system will allow you to do that.

When a transaction hits your PayPal account their server will POST data to a URL that you specify.  Within that URL/script you can receive that data and process it however you need.

In this case you would make a call to the [Google Group API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to update your group data accordingly based on the data in the IPN.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the Answer.
How can i do it?

Thanks